# Solving vector valued differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I want to solve the following differential equation

$$y'(t) = f(y(t),t)$$

where the right hand side is a function that has no closed form expression.

I have a vector of numerical values representing $f(y)$. It is time independent (each value corresponds to a grid point in y). How can I solve the differential equation?

I tried solving this as a loop as follows:

$$y(t+\Delta t) = y(t) + \Delta t f(y(t),t)$$

I use interpolation on the the second term. The problem is that this is very slow and I wonder if this can be solved more efficiently.

I would like to calculate how long it takes for $y(t_0)$ to reach a given value $y(T)$. For instance, in the graphs shown below, I want to know how long it takes to reach $\underline{y}$ for every point in the grid of $y$. How could I do this?

[image]

Comment: Numerically, you can define $f$ as a spline function and then use the solver of your choice (e,g, Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg).

Comment: How can I use Runge-Kutta if the vector of numerical values representing the rate of change, $f(y)$, at each grid point $y$ is time independent?

Comment: The graph on the right seems to indicate that $\dot y>0,$ but in the graph on the left $\dot y$ is negative. Also, why do you sometimes write $\underline y$ with a bar underneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned Runge-Kutta methods in your tags to this question.
Such methods assume the problem can be stated in the form
$y'(t) = f(y(t),t).$ They do *not* assume that $f$ is sensitive to both of its inputs; you could have $f(y,t) = 1 + e^{-y}$ (or some other function that depended only on $y$) and that would be perfectly fine.

The standard application of a Runge-Kutta method to $y'(t) = f(y(t),t)$ 
means you choose a new value of $t$ at which to end each "step," so you end up with a list of function values $y(t_0)$ (where $t_0$ is your initial value of $t$), $y(t_1),$ $y(t_2),$ $y(t_3),$ and so forth. That is, you have a table  of values of $y$ as a function of $t.$

Any of the usual Runge-Kutta methods should work and should produce such a table of values if you make sure to remember what the values of $y$ and $t$  were at the end of each step.

But it seems you really want $t$ as a function of $y.$
In fact that is what your "time to reach" figure represents if you
consider it as the graph of a function with the input value on the horizontal axis and the output value on the vertical axis.
If your $y$ is really just a real-valued strictly increasing function of time, as depicted in that figure, it is reasonable to think of the relation between $t$ and $y$ that way.

In that case, you could consider this equation:
$$
\frac{dt}{dy} = \frac{1}{f(y)}.
$$
Integrate both sides with respect to $y$:
$$
t\big\rvert_{y=y_1} - t\big\rvert_{y=y_0} = \int_{y_0}^{y_1} \frac{1}{f(y)}\,dy.
$$
If $y_0 = y(0),$ then $t\big\rvert_{y=y_0} = 0,$ so you can write $t(y)$
($t$ as a function of $y$) as follows: 
$$
t(y) = \int_{y_0}^{y} \frac{1}{f(u)}\,du.
$$
Your table of values of $f(y)$ lets you directly derive a table of values of $\frac{1}{f(u)},$ so now you're just integrating a function over an interval. 
You can use the trapezoid method, Simpson's method, or some other single-variable numeric integration, depending on what kind of guesses you want to make about the values of $\frac{1}{f(u)}$ in between the known values.

Runge-Kutta methods would still work, but seem to be overkill for a problem posed in that form.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would still have to use interpolation to calculate $f(y+\Delta y)$ if $y+\Delta y$ lies between points in my $y$ grid. This is ok. The issue that confuses me with Runge Kutta is that I also have to interpolate values at $f(y+\Delta y, t + \Delta t)$. For instance, in page 16 of this document http://www.ehu.eus/aitor/irakas/fin/apuntes/pde.pdf, the 4th order Runge Kutta method. Im very confused about this.

Comment: As far as finding $t$, this has been resolved with your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: If $\dot y = f(y,t)$ depends only on $y,$ not $t,$ then you can write $f(y,t)=g(y)$ and therefore $f(y+\Delta y, t+\Delta t)=g(y+\Delta y).$ Either the "$t$" input to $f$ matters when you evaluate $f$ (in which case you had better have values for $f(y,t)$ for multiple values of $t$ as well as multiple values of $y$) or the "$t$" input does not matter (even when it is some complicated expression).

Answer (score 1):

The problem of the interpolation being slow depends on your interpolator. If your vector is known at equally spaced points, I recommend the cubic B-spline discussed by [Kress](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387984087), which required $O(N)$ construction and $O(1)$ evaluation.

Next, your integration method is $O(\Delta t)$-accurate, which is horrible. Try a higher-order method, like Runge-Kutta and it will speed up dramatically.

Comment: Thank you for the references

Comment: How can I implement the Runge Kutta method if I have $f(y)$ and not $f(y,t)$? I only have the rate of change in $y$ as a function of the grid point in $y$ space. The function is independent of time.